# Quasinilpotent example

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quasinilpotent operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84964/quasinilpotent-operator)

Do you know any example of a quasinilpotent operator such that every its power is non-compact?

Of course direct sum of nilpotent operators(or Volterra operator) can by good. But I search for same known("classical") example.

Comment: This appears to be identical to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84964/quasinilpotent-operator which was closed two days ago.  It seems pointless to just repeat a question which the community felt was not suitable for this site...

Answer (score 2):

In http://www.jstor.org/pss/2047905 you can find a weighted shift operator that has this property.